# Why is it showing me an error while print, in a plain game project?

Tags: swift, printing

I have created an empty Game Project. I tried to use "print" to start with, but got an error right away. I have no idea what could be wrong, I'm a beginner.
[image]

Comment: print it inside any function.

Comment: Your code is "nowhere". You need to put it into a method.

Answer (score 0):

The print statement you write must be written in another method.